# Reverse text file writing in QT

Tags: qt, reverse, qfile

How is it better to implement writing to QFile in reverse order, string by string.

With use of seek(0) new string is written over old one.

Comment: Do you want to write to a file from the end to the beginning, or do you just want to reverse a text file?

Comment: I need to write to a file from end to the beginning. I don't have the file, I have a data to write.

Comment: I don't think that's actually possible at the FS/OS level. You should revert your data first and then write it sequentially. The closest you can get to writing it backwards is to pad it to the end, the seek each byte, from end to beginning, and write byte by byte. That's not a good strategy, if you have enough memory you should stack everything up and then unstack and write each of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a [`QStack`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstack.html#details) of QString. Since it's a LIFO (Last In First Out) container I think it's what you are searching for.

Push each string as they come and then pop all strings:

```
QStack<QString> stack;
stack.push("first string");
stack.push("second string");
stack.push("third string");

while (!stack.isEmpty())
{
   QString string = stack.pop();
}
```

**Edit**: (new information in comments concerning the 2 files to write)

Use a [`Qvector`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html) to store all QString. Then in a for loop access first and last element to write them in each file. This can be done like this:

```
QVector<QString> vector;
vector.append("first string");
vector.append("second string");
vector.append("third string");

int size = vector.size();
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
   QString string1 = vector[0]; // write it in one file
   Qstring string2 = vector[size-1-i]; // write it in another file
}
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks.
The matter is that I have few QList<QString>.
And I need to save these strings twice, the first in direct order the second in reverse.
And I would like to write both files in once and do not create duplicates of my strings in reverse order.
Bu it seems that there is no other way as to collect all the strings in one list or stack and read the list twice in direct and reverse order....

Comment: So you can use a QVector since you can directly access to an element. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Read all the file. Save it to a vector of QStrings in the memory. Go trough the vector reversing all the strings and save this vector to the file again.